# Stopping Apache Storm the right way

Tags: java, apache-storm

Is there a clean way to stop storm without killing it with `kill XXX` where XXX is the PID?

I run `storm kill topology-name` to kill the topology, but after that, is there a clean way to shutdown workers, nimbus, supervisor and ui?

I didn't find any command which corresponds to this from the documentation: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Command-line-client

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Command to kill a topology (as you rightly mentioned):

```
storm kill topology-name
```

To shutdown the cluster you need to run the following command on each node:

```
sudo service supervisord stop
```

*Note:* give `supervisord` a few seconds to shutdown all processes. Note that trying to run `supervisorctl` when supervisord itself is stopped will result in an error message (this appears to be a known user interface issue in supervisord 2.x)

From [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/#stop-the-storm-cluster) documentation

> How to kill ALL Storm processes including worker processes? Any worker threads (launched by the Supervisor daemons on the slave nodes) that happen to be running when you are stopping the cluster will continue to run. This is a deliberate design decision of Storm because it means that crashing/restarting Nimbus and Supervisor daemons will not affect any running topologies in Storm. The downside is that you have to put some extra effort into fully stopping all Storm-related processes in a cluster.

If you want to kill ALL processes follow this procedure on the slave nodes:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl stop storm-supervisor
$ sudo pkill -TERM -u storm -f 'backtype.storm.daemon.worker'
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks for pointing out Supervisor with a great link.

Comment: It works well, still I had to put the full command (with java -server -Dstorm.options...) for supervisord to work with storm in supervisord.conf, it seems like a python bug between storm and supervisord. Great to stop all, and to have supervision with auto-restart and logs.

Comment: @zenbeni - if you feel it is a bug, report it via the bug / issue tracker.  Telling >>us<< about it isn't going to get the issue fixed.

Answer (score 3):

From the page that you linked to:

> *kill*
>
> *Syntax: storm kill topology-name [-w wait-time-secs]*
>
> *Kills the topology with the name topology-name. Storm will first deactivate the topology's spouts for the duration of the topology's message timeout to allow all messages currently being processed to finish processing. Storm will then shutdown the workers and clean up their state. You can override the length of time Storm waits between deactivation and shutdown with the -w flag.*

As you can see, this is designed to give you a "clean" shutdown.  The kill command shuts down the workers.

Comment: +1, no need to kill Storm worker processes manually, since `storm kill topology-name` will kill them for you. Afterwards, with no topologies running anymore on the cluster, you kill the Supervisor and Nimbus processes (and optionally the Storm UI and DRPC processes).

Comment: It is good to know. Still, I feel that you need some abstraction on storm processes, because I don't want to manually kill each process and restart them. And there are times when I want everything to be shutdowned. Supervisord seems more elegant and I was asking for not "kill" each process anyway including ui, nimbus and supervisor (supervisord does it, not me).

Comment: I see.  Yes ... if you have multiple topologies then "storm kill" is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have  started storm as ./storm nimbus & ./storm supervisor & ./storm ui then

after that you may forgot the process id's in that case you can use jps tool to find out pid's then kill them as

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps

3201 ConsoleConsumer

7528 Jps

2966 Kafka

3680 nimbus

3681 supervisor

6749 Launcher

2669 QuorumPeerMain

killing nimbus first

$ sudo kill 3681

$ sudo kill 3680

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna kill all the topologies in one go :

```
bin/storm kill `bin/storm list | grep <some common keyword>  | awk '{print $1}'` -w 5
```