# Stopping apache storm nimbus and supervisor

Tags: apache-storm

I started storm nimbus and supervisor with following command,

```
sudo storm nimbus &
sudo storm supervisor &
```

Is there a way to stop the cluster without using kill -9 processes

Comment: This link might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926548/stopping-storm-the-right-way